# How to use the Observable cascade AJAX multiple methods

Tags: rxjs5

[live exmaple](https://jsfiddle.net/wz9gjqp2/)

I would have expected it to be printed in order:

- Turn on the Loading screen before sending Ajax results
- get AJAX results and records
- Close the Loading screen

The following code can be executed, and I would like to ask whether there are other ways to write

```js
var openLoadingPage$ = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  console.log("open...");
  observer.complete();
});

var closeLoadingPage$ = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  console.log("close..");
  observer.complete();
});

var ajax$ = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  //todo:get ajax result
  observer.next("hello world");
  observer.complete();
});

var result$ = Rx.Observable.of(
    openLoadingPage$,
    ajax$.delay(2000),
    closeLoadingPage$)
  .concatAll();

result$.subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log("get ajax result:", value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that when you write `Rx.Observable.of(myFunc1())`, `myFunc1` is executed right away and its return value (`undefined` in your case, because it has none) will be the single event value for the observable.

(same issue with `subscribe`, which takes a callback, when you pass the return value of `console.log("complete")`)

You're probably going to have more success by writing `.subscribe(() => console.log("complete")`) for the last part.

For the func part, it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, but here's an attempt:

```js
function myFunc1() {
  console.log("myFunc subscribe called");
  return "f1"
}

function myFunc2() {
  console.log("myFunc2 subscribe called");
  return "f2"
}

var myFunc1$ = Rx.Observable.defer(() => Rx.Observable.of(myFunc1()));
var myFunc2$ = Rx.Observable.defer(() => Rx.Observable.of(myFunc2()));

myFunc1$
  .delay(2000)
  .concat(myFunc2$)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks,It works, but I want to get the final result in the Subscribe implementation, so I have to rewrite my question